# Android+android-ndk-r10d+OpenCV-2.4.10 Build Error

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android

I am working with Android+NDK+OpenCV.

I keep getting the following build error

```
 Android NDK: Check that ../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java.so exists  or that its path is correct   
../../android-ndk-r10d/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

My Application.mk file is:

```
 APP_PLATFORM := android-8
 APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64 mips mips64
 APP_OPTIM             := debug
 NDK_DEBUG             := 1

 NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.6
 APP_STL               := gnustl_shared
 APP_CPPFLAGS          := -fexceptions -frtti
```

And my Android.mk file is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
include ../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := document_scanner
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to move `include ../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk` below `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`

Comment: I don’t understand your answer.

Comment: What is the difference. Is there any specific reason.

Comment: Half of my answer was missing for format reason, sorry for that. Another issue was also due to `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64 mips mips64`. In my case i can't compile lib with the arm64-v8a archi

Comment: What can be the reason for not compiling. Is there anything that I am missing here.

Comment: In my SDK folder in `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs` i only have `armeabi` `armeabi-v7a` `mips` and `x86` folders, maybe it can't find libs you want to include for some architectures like `arm64-v8a` or `mips64` if you have not the right folder.

Comment: I've also notified that. I don’t understand why the sdk does not contain arm64-v8a or mips64 support.